# Use LSTM to predict the proportion of steps with nonzero feature values

Tags: classification, lstm, keras, recurrent-neural-network, sequential-pattern-mining

I am trying to do a simple regression for sequences. Each input $X_i$ is a $n=2000$ by 1 matrix, formatted as $n_i$ 0-s followed by $(n-n_i)$ 1-s. The output $y_i$ should be $n_i/n$, i.e. the proportion of steps with nonzero feature values.

The code for generating the data

```py
ns = [1087, 280, 1013, 300, 311, 260, 960, 281, 417, 311, 102, 251, 748, 428, 802, 512, 61, 80, 1700, 693, 147, 577, 280, 196, 377, 281, 88, 359, 250, 330, 679, 201, 284, 1129, 151, 285, 722, 1014, 153, 202, 256, 99, 661, 415, 134, 269, 196, 137, 436, 617]
Xs = np.array([[[0] for i in range(2000-x)]+[[1] for i in range(x)] for x in ns])
Ys = np.mean(Xs,axis=(1,2))
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = Xs[:45], Xs[45:], Ys[:45], Ys[45:]
```

I tried to use LSTM and an output layer to do the prediction, i.e.

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.00, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],trainX.shape[2])))
model.add((LSTM(10,activation='tanh',unit_forget_bias=True,input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],trainX.shape[2]))))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
model.compile(optimizer=adam(),loss='mse',metrics=['mae'],)
model.fit(trainX,trainY,epochs=50,validation_data=(testX,testY),verbose=1)
```

Yet I found the model fails to predict what I want, instead it predicts every sequence with almost the same $y$ value. Just wondering if there's any solution to solve this?

Comment: I suppose the first question is 'why do you want to do this?' Is it a simplification of a bigger problem?

Comment: Yes, Y here is a simplification of signals that I wanted to capture...

Comment: But the inputs have a similar format? An LSTM seems a strange choice from the information I've got. The proportion of ones fully describes the input vector, so why not just use the proportion as the predictor?